# Windows 10 Phone - Network File Share

Tags: windows-10-mobile, networking, file-explorer

is it possible to access files on a network share from Windows 10 Phone? I have a 640 XL and I'd love to view some pictures/videos located at `\\MyServer\Media`.

I'd prefer not to have to use Cloud (OneDrive, Dropbox, etc), Sharepoint or other intermediaries...

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to install an app for this as this seems not to be possible out of the box. [Total Commander](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/total-commander/9wzdncrfjwf1#) should be able to access network shares - there are probably a few others as well.

Comment: More than willing to do apps (That's what phones do after all). Just hadn't seen the magic words in quick searches.

Comment: Have you tried this app?

Comment: I have it installed but hadn't needed it since the day I initially asked. it seems like it has everything I needed (NAS browsing) but I hadn't gotten past the VPN portion (Work is wireless access point followed by VPN tunnel).